# Rails request.create in rsa-sha256?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, encryption, cryptography, saml

I am working on SAML authentication

I have settings with digest and signature method in **rsa-sha256**, but when I create the request to redirect a authenticating user the request is in **rsa-sha1** ...

In the url, there is `SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1`

But I want it to be `rsa-sha256`

**Settings :**

```
  def saml_settings
    settings = OneLogin::RubySaml::Settings.new({:idp_cert_fingerprint_algorithm            => XMLSecurity::Document::SHA256})

    settings.assertion_consumer_service_url = "..."
    settings.issuer                         = "..."
    settings.idp_sso_target_url             = "..."
    settings.name_identifier_format         = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"
    #settings.authn_context = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport"
    settings.certificate = CONFIG_CERTIFICATE
    settings.private_key = CONFIG_PRIVATE_KEY
    settings.security[:authn_requests_signed]  = true     # Enable or not signature on AuthNRequest
    settings.security[:logout_requests_signed] = true     # Enable or not signature on Logout Request
    settings.security[:logout_responses_signed] = true     # Enable or not signature on Logout Response

    settings.security[:digest_method]    = XMLSecurity::Document::SHA256
    settings.security[:signature_method] = XMLSecurity::Document::SHA256

    settings.security[:embed_sign]        = false


    settings
  end
```

and when I create the **request** :

```
request = OneLogin::RubySaml::Authrequest.new
redirect_to(request.create(saml_settings))
```

Here, `request.create(saml_settings)`  is returning the In the url, there is `SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1`

How can I change this to be in **rsa-sha256?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found the anwser :

In the lib, the sha1 ou sha256 ecryption will be defined by the settings,

in the method `create_params` of `OneLogin::RubySaml::Authrequest`  we have

```
if settings.security[:authn_requests_signed] && !settings.security[:embed_sign] && settings.private_key
  params['SigAlg'] = XMLSecurity::Document::SHA1
  ... 
end
```

so, I had

```
settings.security[:embed_sign]        = false
```

And so the condition was TRUE. But it has to be **FALSE**

so I've put

```
settings.security[:embed_sign]        = true
```

(actually, it has to be at true)

and

```
request.create(saml_settings, {:SigAlg => XMLSecurity::Document::SHA256}))
```

And it's done !

( cf http://www.rubydoc.info/github/onelogin/ruby-saml/OneLogin/RubySaml/Authrequest#create-instance_method )